# Visual Studio C++ PlaySound identifier is undefined

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am going through Charles Petzold - Programming Windows(5th Edition)  Chapter 3.  I have an error stating that PlaySound function is undefined. In there some sort of header file I need to include to use this function?

```
/*−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
HELLOWIN.C −− Displays "Hello, Windows 98!" in client area
(c) Charles Petzold, 1998
−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−*/

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("HelloWin");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"),
            szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, // window class name
        TEXT("The Hello Program"), // window caption
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, // window style
        CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial x position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial y position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial x size
        CW_USEDEFAULT, // initial y size
        NULL, // parent window handle
        NULL, // window menu handle
        hInstance, // program instance handle
        NULL); // creation parameters
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

More comment: playsound should be legal function based on link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        PlaySound(TEXT("HelloWin.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Hello, Windows 98!"), -1, &rect,
            DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message you're receiving. You may find it easier to copy from the Output Tab (located near the Error List Tab) because the Output Tab deals in plain text. In addition, because the Error List is intended to look pretty, it often leaves out information that can be found in the Output Tab. Sometimes the extra information in the Output Tab is all you need to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you link against `Winmm.lib` as specified in the documentation you linked?

Comment: _Is there some sort of header file I need to include to use this function?_ Yes: mmsystem.h, and the documentation you link to says as much.  See also RetiredNinja's comment (again, as stated in the documentation).

Comment: Side note: I'm not sure a book on Windows programming targeting Windows 98 is a good way to learn Windows programming in 2020. The oldies-but-goodies haven't been removed from the API, but there are often better idioms to follow and newer additions to the API to make your life easier (or at least less buggy). For example the whole `TEXT` thing (easily convert programs from ANSI to UNICODE) has been pretty much a non-issue for the last 15 years

Answer (score 1):

Link against the library and include the header file:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")
#include <mmsystem.h>

int main()
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("HelloWin.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent example of code to play sound that is not mentioned in the current modern API.
This is for the user who wants to use this code:

The Petold code for Chap02  contains this part of the code:
Here we have 2 strings for playing `sound( file name, ...)` and for `DrawText(hdc, "text to draw") .... )` This required modification for both strings from the `const char = old` ASCII string type.

1. As mentioned here using `TEXT("solved the problem")` the error state `LPCWSTR L(..)`,
   type, which did not work? But TEXT did work and was compiled with headings, as stated in the reply.
2. The second string error asking to use `DrawTextW()` now placed `LPCWSTR L(...)`, did not work.
   `DrawTextW(hdc, LPCWSTR("My First Window")` did accept the `'LPCWSTR ("...")`, but without `....L("...")`.

The code was read from the Chap02 file as .c and opened as text file using "WordPad" because it has no paging for long text, then applied to a the compiled winproc...

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC         hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT        rect;
    switch (iMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            //PlaySound("hellowin.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
            //LPCWSTR message1 = L("hellowin.wav");
            PlaySound(TEXT( "hellowin.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
            return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            // LPCWSTR message = L"My First Window";
            DrawTextW(hdc, 
                      LPCWSTR (  "My First Window" ), 
                      -1, 
                      &rect, 
                      DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, 
    lParam);
}
```